# How to fetch database result as a stream using PHP/Zend Framework1

Tags: php, zend-framework, stream

I'm writing a CSV file with the results from a function that returns database query results as an array, and getting memory out of exception if the result set is large.

So I'm looking for writing CSV using streams, can anyone help me how to do this using PHP or Zend Framework-1.

Comment: Please, add the code of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your function to return a *statement*, not full results. You can use `fetch` method to get database results per-row and `fputcsv` to write into a csv file.

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE smth IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```